# JavaScript when was a key released

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function, if a key was released, because I program a little Jump'n'Run and for that I have to know that, because if I use a "normal" handler which is called if a key is pressed, it don't works, because the handler is not called often enough.
I don't want to use jquery or something else, only native JavaScript.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would using key up call the event more often than using key down?

Comment: So use the [onkeyup  event?](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the snipper below. I think this is all you're looking for.

```
 document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  alert('keyup event\n\n' + 'key: ' + keyName);
});
```

Comment: (switch it to keyup--he's looking for the key being released)

Comment: This should be `keyup` instead

Answer (score 3):

[MDN documentation for `keyup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)

```js
document.getElementById('myField').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log(`keyup event fired for key: ${e.key}`);
});
```

```html
Type here: <input id="myField" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (){
    // do something
});
```